# Sending headers in beforeFilter of Controller in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-2.0, http-status-codes

I have myController which is extended from AppController.
Inside myController::beforeFilter I put this line:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
```

But I can't see this data inside response headers.
I don't have any whitespace inside this class neither in AppController.
Where should I look or how can I debug this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using PHP's header function, you'll want to use Cake's:

In `AppController::beforeFilter`:

```
$this->header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

Using Cake's built in `header` function queues the headers and sends them all at once when it's ready. I think your problem is likely because you're outputting a header at the wrong time.

Comment: Also I should mention that sending headers from controller file is deprecated, it should be sent from view file.

Comment: I can't seem to find where it says this method is deprecated - can you provide a link?

Comment: You can check this: http://api20.cakephp.org/file/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#method-Controllerheader

Comment: Isn't it only the wrapper function that is deprecated? CakeResponse::header is still what you should use (also I don't see anything about putting this in the view).